# How to make a screen-record guiding video for iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, replaykit

I'm creating an iOS app on recording screen by using ReplayKit.
I want to make a user operation video to guide user on how to use my app to record screen.
So I need to record a video on how to record screen and this approach is a bit awkward.
I tried several ways: Screen Mirroring such as AirPlayer and QuickTime, but the recording button on control-center is disabled whilst using Screen Mirroring.

The effect I want is as follows:
https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/iOS/ios13-iphone-xs-control-center-screen-record-animation.gif

How was this video made?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could recreate that video by recording your screen showing every action you want, save the video and edit it on top of an iPhone image asset.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The key to my question is how to record screens on recording screen.